# Panel shows nothing if setLayout is null

Tags: java, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I have created a JPanel and added a JTabbedPane to it. Then I added another two panels to this tabbedpane and i setLayout as null for all panels. But the Frame shows nothing and if I change the layout from null to BorderLayout or GridLayout for the main panel then it works perfect. Can someone tell me what is the problem here.. Thanks in Advance

My Code:
I am creating objects for each component and setting bounds for them in the specified getters by checking null constraint

First Panel:

```
public class InsurancePanel extends JPanel
{
public InsurancePanel()
{
    getJpInsurance();
}

private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

public void getJpInsurance()
{
    setLayout(null);
    add(getJlLICName());
    add(getJlCompany());

    add(getJtfLICName());
    add(getJtfCompany());

    add(getJbUpdate());
}
}
```

Second Panel:

```
public class PatientPanel extends JPanel
{

public PatientPanel()
{
    getJpPatient();
 }

private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

public void getJpPatient()
{
    setLayout(null);
    add(getJlFirstName());
    add(getJlLastName());

    add(getJtfFirstName());
    add(getJtfLastName());

    add(getJbNew());
}
}
```

And the MainPanel:

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel
{
private PatientPanel        m_PatientPanel;
private InsurancePanel      m_InsurancePanel;
private JTabbedPane jtpView;

public void designMainPanel()
{
    setLayout(new GridLayout()); // if it is null, then nothing shows in the frame
    setSize(650, 520);
    setBounds(0, 0, 650, 520);
    add(getJtpView());
}

public JTabbedPane getJtpView()
{
    if (jtpView == null)
    {
        jtpView = new JTabbedPane();
        jtpView.addTab("Patient", getPatientPanel());
        jtpView.addTab("Insurance", getInsurancePanel());
    }
    return jtpView;
}

    public PatientPanel getPatientPanel()
{
    if (m_PatientPanel == null)
    {
        m_PatientPanel = new PatientPanel();
    }
    return m_PatientPanel;
}

public InsurancePanel getInsurancePanel()
{
    if (m_InsurancePanel == null)
    {
        m_InsurancePanel = new InsurancePanel();
    }
    return m_InsurancePanel;
}

}
```

Comment: you should specified bound of child when you add components to null layout outherwise your child component has 0 dimension and can't see
but use layout .using null layout is very bad.

Comment: yes, but I am new to swings. So I want to get it work with no layout. And I tried by setting bounds also, even it not works

Comment: then you should post your code to see what's wrong..ok .edit your question by adding your not working code

Comment: edited my question with the source code, so please look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in this method

```
public void designMainPanel()
{
    setLayout(null); // if it is null, then nothing shows in the frame
    setSize(650, 520);
    setBounds(0, 0, 650, 520); // ←---- problem is here
    add(getJtpView());
}
```

when you add child components to parent container you should specified x,y location and width,height of the child component.
in this code your parent component is `MainPanel`
and you are trying to add `getJtpView() JTabbedPane` which is child component .but you are set bounds to parent component not to the child (`getJtpView() JTabbedPane`).

you should change it to

```
public void designMainPanel() {
    setLayout(null); //here it's null but it's working now
    JTabbedPane tab1 = getJtpView();
    tab1.setBounds(0, 0, 650, 520); //←---fixed:set bound to child JTabbedPane 
    add(tab1);
}
```

as you can see we set bound for child component-jtabbedpane

```
tab1.setBounds(0, 0, 650, 520);
```

Comment: thaq for your solution. It works perfectly, but for the first time when I launch my application It was showing PatientPanel but the two tabs are not visible. And when I click on the place where the tabs are located, then it changes to other panel. And tabs are visible.

Comment: @SaikiranGosikonda if you can post your all classes not here but somewhere like http://pastebin.com/ i can check it and help .

Comment: ok, I figured out the problem. I am calling setVisible(true) for two times on a frame. And thanks for answer